# How to autostart and instance of MSSQLLocalDB (Microsoft SQL Express 2016)

Tags: sql-server

Is is possible to autostart an instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Express 2016.

This is currently on a Windows 10 system.

When I run sqllocaldb.exe info I get:
[command line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqcoE.jpg)

Everything works fine, except that I have to manually start it everytime.
*for those wanting to know how to do this the command line string is
[command line screenshot starting MSSQLLocalDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7pr8.png)

Or if you cannot see that picture then: **sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb**

**Reiterating my question: Is it possible to start this at system boot up?**

Answer (score 1):

Make a batch file containing only the command starting SQL Server Express and add a shortcut to it in the Windows Startup folder.
Details about how to auto start an executable when booting Windows can be found for instance here: https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/